# Oracle SQL Query not working in .PC file (C Code)

Tags: oracle, oracle-pro-c

Hi I have the following c file ResolveClients.pc
In the file ResolveClients.pc I am executing an Oracle SQL Select Query

```
EXEC SQL AT DHDB
    SELECT  CLIENT_NO
    INTO    :TmpCNo:TmpCNoInd
    FROM    CLIENTS
    WHERE   DATE_OF_BIRTH = to_date(:DOB, 'YYYYMMDD')
    AND FIRSTNAME || ' ' || SURNAME = upper(:Name)
    AND ROWNUM < 2;
```

I've declared

VARCHAR Name    [240]

and DOB is declared as

char  DOB [9]

The string stored in Name.arr is "John Smith" 
and the string stored in DOB is "20010916"

when I execute the exact same query in PL SQL Developer I am finding the record but I am not finding the record using  ResolveClient.pc

Please help indicate where I might be going wrong in the ResolveClient.pc code
Thanks

Comment: I'm not really a pro*c person, but it looks like you're trying to select CLIENT_NO into 2 variables, `:TmpCNo` and `:TmpCNoInd`. Is that right?

Comment: Could you share the code where you set the values of "Name" and "DOB" variable please?

Answer (score 0):

I would try trimming the name field in the comparison in case you have extra white space from your varchar(240) causing the issue.

```
AND trim(FIRSTNAME || ' ' || SURNAME) = trim(upper(:Name))
```